# MasterPage - Issue with label displaying the username

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have a master page that has a lot of "Logged in pages" using it. On the master page I put a simple label and put code in the page load method to change the label to the username, but it doesn't. The label shows up on all my pages, but the label is never changed.

In the page load for master page.

```
lblUserName.Text = Page.User.Identity.Name;
```

What else is there?

If I do something simple like this on my Logged in homepage, it works, but I want to use it on multiple pages from the master page.

Comment: What do you mean by "The label shows up on all my pages, but the label is never changed"? What is the label text then?

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a declaration on the content page, if so then your line setting the label value will not be run.

Look in your Master.master file (not your master.master.cs), does it start with a line such as :

```
<%@ Master Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Master.master.cs"
    Inherits="Master" %>
```

If not, if it starts with some html (eg. a doctype `<!DOCTYPE html>`) then the problem is that your code page is never being called.